# Communicating with other fragments when using the Actionbar.tablistner interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

The use of [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) tutorial is very clear to me however I am using the Actionbar.tablistner interface. How can I pass variables(strings) from fragment to fragment using this interface?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface with a method which accepts any variable (e.g. String). Something like this:

```
public interface TabClickedListener {
   public void passParam(String var);
}
```

Implement this interface in your Activity. From the Actionbar.tablistener onTabSelected() method call the above interface method (on the activity instance you have) passing whatever value you would like. Once you receive this value in your Activity you can pass this to a different Fragment.

Comment: The thing is that the activity already implements a interface `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener` so I can't implement a second one as far as I know that's the problem otherwise I could use the tutorial

Comment: You can implement as many interfaces you want in Java. The same is not true for extending classes. Basic java my friend :).

Comment: Thanks so much I wish I knew this earlier.